# GitHub Not Recognizing Passed Client ID and Secret

Tags: api, github, oauth

By registering your application you can increase your rate limit for GitHub's API from 60 to 5000 requests[[1]](http://developer.github.com/changes/2012-10-14-rate-limit-changes/). You don't have to use OAuth and can simply pass you're client ID and secret in the URL to have GitHub recognize your application[[2]](http://developer.github.com/v3/#unauthenticated-rate-limited-requests). But when I curl the rate limit check:

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/ratelimit?client_id=xxx&client_secret=yyy
```

The following is returned:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Sat, 13 Jul 2013 01:53:50 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Status: 200 OK
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 51
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1373683093
X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.beta
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Length: 55
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
ETag: "[redacted]"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Vary: Accept-Encoding

{"rate":{"limit":60,"remaining":51,"reset":1373683093}}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Do I really have to use the full OAuth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the URL in quotes when running the command fixed the problem.

Comment: I have to upvote your answer, even if your solution does not work with JSON Api request.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that you can also register "Personal Access Tokens" from the Applications menu option inside GitHub. This gives you a token with the increased 5,000 API calls/hour without having to do the OAuth dance.

Comment: I am trying to access